# QSqlTableModel notify on rows inserted

Tags: mysql, qsqltablemodel

How do I get notified if a record has been inserted into mysql table by another database client, is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

```
void QSqlTableModel::beforeInsert(QSqlRecord &record)
```

This signal is emitted by **insertRowIntoTable()** before a new row is inserted into the currently active database table. The values that are about to be inserted are stored in record and can be modified before they will be inserted.

Comment: Thanks, yes seen that, but will this work if multiple clients are operating on the database table, for example two different connection s to database? If that makes sense

Answer (score 0):

QSqlDriver supports notifications , however not for Mysql